# React setState hook is not working when trying to clear/empty/delete/set back to initial state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror, setstate, use-state

I have a `clearState` function which sets some useState hooks back to their initial state when the restart button is clicked. However, they say that my setState is not a function. Please check code below:

**App.js**

```
...
const [question, setQuestion] = useState(0);
const [response, setResponse] = useState({});
const [answer, setAnswer] = useState({});
const [answerId, setAnswerId] = useState({});
...
```

**Modal.js**

```
const Modal = ({
  setResponse,
  setAnswer,
  setAnswerId,
  setQuestion,
  setAnswerNameArr,
}) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const clearState = () => {
    setOpen(false); //works
    setQuestion(0); //works
    setAnswer({}); //does not work
    setAnswerId({});
    setResponse({});
    setAnswerNameArr([]);
  };

...

  return (
    <Modal
       ...
    >
      ...
        <Button
           onClick={()=>handleSubmit()}
        >
           Restart
        </Button>
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

The error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: setAnswer is not a function
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you aren't passing your state setting hooks in to your `<Modal>` so they're not available.

It isn't a good idea to do that anyway, tbh. If you need a child to affect the state of a parent it would be better to pass a single call-back:

```
const Modal = ({
      onSubmitCb
}) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const clearState = () => {
    setOpen(false); //works
    setQuestion(0); //works
    onSubmitCb && onSubmitCb()
  };

...

  return (
    <Modal>
      ...
        <Button
           onClick={()=>handleSubmit()}
        >
           Restart
        </Button>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

and in your parent:

```
const App = ()=>{
    const clearState = () => {
        setAnswer({});
        setAnswerId({});
        setResponse({});
        setAnswerNameArr([]);
  };
  
  .... 

  return {
      <Modal ... onSubmitCb={clearState} />
   }
}
```